# Is this correct? Using performSelector instead of just calling the method straight

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, performselector

I'm trying to close a superview by using this method `[self.superview buttonPressedClose];`

I have already implemented that method in my superview, and everything works.

But it gives me an alert "**UIView may not respond to 'buttonPressedClose'**" during compile.

If I change it to the following line, it doesn't give me the alert, but is this the correct way to do it?

```
if ([self.superview respondsToSelector:@selector(buttonPressedClose)]) {
    [self.superview performSelector:@selector(buttonPressedClose) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
}
```

Thanks.

**Edited typo..

Answer (score 4):

Is this a typo in question or in your code?

```
if ([self.superview respondsToSelector:@selector(buttonPressedClose)]) {
                                                   //  vv here
[self.superview performSelector:@selector(buttonPressedCLose) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
}
```

In general, `self.superview` returns an object of type `UIView`, and your `buttonPressedClose` is a custom selector that's not implemented in `UIView`. That's why you're getting a warning.

You might want to cast `self.superview` to your desired type, e.g.:

```
[(MyView *)self.superview buttonPressedClose];
```

or make it even more mysterious and cast to `id` - compiler doesn't check for selectors presence then:

```
[(id)self.superview buttonPressedClose];
```

That said, all of the above solutions are a bit smelly.

One **very important** thing regarding `performSelector:` with zero delay - it doesn't execute the selector in place, but rather it posts selector execution to thread's run loop and executes it when control returns to the run loop (i.e. when call stack is empty). So in normal situations you wouldn't like to use it.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, typo, should be `[self.superview performSelector:@selector(buttonPressedClose) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];`

Answer (score 0):

"is this the correct way to do it?"

No, there is no reason to do it this way. `afterDelay:0` is only used if you want to not execute it immediately. If you want to execute it immediately, then you should use `performSelector:` without `afterDelay:`.

But using `performSelector:` directly like this has no benefit. It is equivalent to, and is a more convoluted way of, calling the method directly. The warning you are getting is purely a static type-checking issue. The type (`UIView *`) is not guaranteed to have that method. You need to cast it to the expected view type that supports the method, or cast it to `id` to turn off checking of methods. When you used `performSelector:`, that also skirts around static type checking of methods, so it is strictly no better than casting it to `id` and then calling it.